# How does $u$ solving the equation $x^2 - x -1 = 0$ imply $u = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\xi_5 = e^{2 \pi i / 5}$ and $u = - ( \xi^2_5 + \xi^3_5 )$. How does u solving the equation $x^2 - x -1 = 0 $ imply $u = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solving the quadratic equation we get
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4}}$$ and we get
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$